# SQL Server 2008 R2 vs. SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

What differences exist between the pay and free version of MSSQL2008R2?
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/R2.aspx
and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Express
http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/
A complete answer might explain why someone would choose one over the other, what the biggest annoyances are with going Express, non-intuitive things to look out for, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Executive summary (Commonly missed features for the person running a small database):

SQL 2008 R2 Express edition is lacking:

- SQL Server Agent (for scheduling jobs, including SQL replication)
- support for DBs >10GB
- Integration services

There are many other differences, detailed at the URL Moose posted.

SQL Express **CAN** be accessed from the network, but it is not enabled by default.  A quick google will show how

Answer (score 5):

This page has a good comparison... The Express version is free, but it's limited in areas.

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx

Answer (score 2):

We often see shortened list of differences between Express and Standard. In my opinion, when you are to the point of considering this for a "production" environment deployment, you need to fully be aware of differences. Here's the full detailed list of differences between 2008R2 Standard and 2008R2 Express from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc645993(v=sql.105).aspx):

**Scalability and Performance**

- Number of CPUs ( *4 v.s. 1* )
- Maximum memory utilized ( *64GB v.s. 1GB* )
- Maximum database size ( *524PB v.s. 10 GB* )
- Direct query of index views using NOEXPAND hint
- Automatic indexed view maintenance

**High Availability**

- Log shipping
- Database mirroring
- Automatic corruption recovery from mirror
- Log stream compression
- Number of Failover clustering nodes ( *2 v.s. 0* )
- Backup compression

**Virtualization Support**

- Guest failover clustering support for virtualization
- Hyper-V live migration

**Replication**

- Publishing data from SQL Server to non SQL Server subscribers

**Single Instance RDBMS Management**

- Dedicated admin connection ( *yes v.s. under trace flag* )
- Policy automation (check on schedule and change)
- Maintenance plans
- Database mail
- Performance data collector
- System Center Operations Manager Management Pack
- Plan Guides
- User instances ( *only for Express* )

**Application and Multi-Instance Management**

- Able to enroll for multi-instance management.

**Management Tools**

- SQL Server Management Studio ( *Standard v.s. [Express](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms365247(v=sql.105).aspx)*)
- SQL Server Agent
- Database Engine Tuning Advisor
- SQL Server Profiler

**Development Tools**

- IntelliSense (Transact-SQL and MDX)
- Business Intelligence Development Studio
- SQL query, edit and design tools
- Version control support
- MDX edit, debug, and design tools

**Programmability**

- Full-text search
- Specification of language in query
- Service Broker (messaging) (*client only for Express*)
- XML/A support
- Web services (HTTP/SOAP endpoints)
- T-SQL endpoints

**Spatial and Location Services**

- Spatial results tab within SQL Server Management Studio

**Complex Event Processing (StreamInsight)**

- StreamInsight

**Integration Services**

- Integration Services designer and runtime
- Basic tasks and transformations in addition to those used by the Import and Export Wizard
- Log providers and logging
- Basic data profiling tools
- Programmable object model for extensibility

**Data Warehouse**

- Auto-generate staging and data warehouse schema

**Analysis Services**

- SQL Server Analysis Services backup
- Dimension, attribute relationship, aggregate, and cube design
- Translations
- Personalization extensions

**Analysis Services-Advanced Analytic Functions**

- Binary and compressed XML transport

**Data Mining**

- Comprehensive set of data mining algorithms
- Integrated data mining tools: wizards, editors, model viewers, query builder

**Reporting**

- Reporting Services memory limits ( *4Gb for Express* )
- Model support
- Model Item Security
- Infinite click-through
- E-mail and file share subscriptions and scheduling
- Report history, executing snapshots, and caching
- SharePoint integration
- Shared component library
- Remote and non-relational data source support
- Data source, delivery, and rendering extensibility
- Report definition customization extension (RDCE)

**Business Intelligence Clients**

- Report Builder 3.0
- Excel 2007 and Visio 2007 Add-in support

Answer (score 0):

The most prominant difference is that SQL Express can only run on 1 of your systems processors rather than multi-proc.   Personally, in my DEV environments I really can't tell the difference in performance.

Comment: On the subject of hardware limitations, express is also limited to 1GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

A few big things come to mind, you don't have an SQL Agent with express, and being a Publisher for replication isn't possible. (Because of not having an agent) And you are limited to the size of your DB.