# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express accepts only local connections?

Tags: remote-access, sql-server-2008, networking

Coming from question [SQL Server 2008 connection](https://serverfault.com/questions/175753/sql-server-2008-connection/175759#175759) tagged under sql-server-2008-express

Chris S wrote in [SQL Server 2008 R2 vs. SQL Server 2008 R2 Express](https://serverfault.com/questions/175351/sql-server-2008-r2-vs-sql-server-2008-r2-express/175438#175438):

- "The biggest different I see others have missed is that Express does not accept network connections (only local ones)"

I am having difficulties to find reference where is it written. Can you give me one?

What are "network connections (only local ones)" - on the same network, in the same AD, inside the same developing machine? Can they be from the same workgroup Windows computer?

Comment: Wow, -4 in a minute! Thanks for downvoting. But I am missing the point from this anonymous guidance - what is the message. Express can or not be connected remotely?

Comment: I case others can't find the Answer he's referring to, I delete it as it was wrong; I had been misinformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not anywhere because you can access SQL server express from the network. It's just not turned on by default, you need to enable network connections manually.

Comment: It is the same in any edition of MS SQL Server

Comment: No. It started I think with 2008 ;) Older versions have it on by default ;)